# Visual Studio / R# Keyboard shortcuts: select string with or without quotes

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I have checked the questions with similar titles, and searched, but found nothing. But I swear I've seen someone do this before.

Say I have something like the following:

```
var mystr = "here is some text I want to select";
```

Is there a way to place the cursor caret within the string, then use a shortcut to select it without quotes? Another shortcut to select with quotes?

If this is available in ReSharper instead, what is the shortcut there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Ctrl + W` (Extend selection) shortcut in Visual Studio. If you are in a word it will select the word, press again and it will select the string without the quotes, then the string with the quotes, then the statement, then the next logical element...

Comment: *Ctrl+W* is a VisualStudio shortcut. ReSharper's equivalent is *Ctrl+Alt+Right*. And the advantage of ReSharper`s solution is its counterpart: *Ctrl+Alt+Left*, which reverts the last selection extension. So if you extend the selection by mistake you can easely revise it by shrinking selection.

Comment: Doesn't work in VS 2017. `Ctrl - W` just selects the current word; pressing it again does not extend the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alt + shift + left` or `alt + shift + right` to select content between the quotes instead of dragging the mouse to select all of content